# How long does it take for a blob to update in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob storage to store images for my new website.

When I have an image called background.jpg and replace it with a different image, but with the same name (background.jpg) it can take up to a week to actually change to the new image on the website.

The only way to test it is to either visit the website through a VPN or use someone else's machine (who's never accessed the website before).

I have cleared my local storage and cache multiple times.

It's almost as if blob storage has it's own caching mechanism on the server side.

I've had a look at the Microsoft Docs, but they are not so straight-forward to understand in this area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the access tier of your container which stored the specific image?

Comment: @DorisLv the access tier is "Hot"

Comment: Hi, @ Joachim Velzel,  if the solution did some help, do you mind accepting it as the answer for others to refer?

Comment: Hello @DorisLv, unfortunately, I have not come further with this. I am using azure storage explorer also, but I might have access to more settings in the Azure Portal.

This problem is not really a show-stopper, it's just annoying that the only way to test is through a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the update in blobs should not be so long. The reason may not only related to blob Storage. You can check it first if the picture in your storage account changed so long either or just your website.

There are three reasons I can imagine:

**1. Using CDN**

Considering you said `"The only way to test it is to either visit the website through a VPN or use someone else's machine"`, you should check if you use CDN on your website.

> In theory, this situation is not very scientific, but the reason is
> very simple and easy to understand. If you don't have record keeping,
> then the manufacturer can only provide you with overseas nodes for
> relay, which will lead to slower access to the content of your
> website, including the image.

**2. Didn't delete browser cache**

Another sentence you said `"I have cleared my local storage and cache multiple times."` I am not sure where the cache you clear, if it is not the browser's cache, you can try clear it too.

**3. Use Cache-Control in Azure Storage**

You should check if you set **[Cache-Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content)** in **Blob Properties**. If you set it, you can do this for not caching: `Cache-Control "private, no-cache"`